# MySQL in Teradata

Tags: mysql

I have a task as follows:

What was the date of the earliest sale in the database where the sale price of the item did not equal the original price of the item, and what was the largest margin (original price minus sale price) of an item sold on that earliest date?

But my code does not work:

```
SELECT saledata, orgprice, sprice 
FROM trnsact 
WHERE sprice<>orgprice 
ORDER BY 'orgprice' - 'sprice' DESC AND saledata ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT saledata, max(orgprice-sprice) as margin
FROM trnsact 
WHERE sprice<>orgprice 
GROUP BY saledata
ORDER BY saledata LIMIT 1
```